# How does Ubuntu determine the default route when multiple interfaces are defined?

Tags: networking, server, default, gateway

I have an Ubuntu server (headless, Network Manager is not installed).  It has two interfaces, eth0 and eth1.  I have the following defined in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.5.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.5.1
dns-search test.domain.com
dns-nameserver 10.0.2.3
broadcast 10.0.5.255

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.57.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.57.1
broadcast 192.168.57.255
```

Currently, after a reboot, /etc/resolve.conf is empty, and my routing table looks like this:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.57.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.5.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Why was the default route chosen to be 192.168.57.1?  eth1 was the first interface in the list.  I would have expected it to get the default route.  What I am wanting to result after a reboot is for /etc/resolve.conf to look like this:

```
search test.domain.com
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

And I want the routing table to look like this:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.5.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.5.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I can get that by manually editing /etc/resolv.conf and with "ip route delete default" "ip route add default ..."  But that doesn't persist through a reboot.

Comment: What if you change the sequence in `/etc/network/interfaces` (first `eth0`, then `eth1`)?

Comment: If I change the sequence, it does end up how I want it.  But it seems too "magical."  I feel that there must be a place where a default route can be defined (instead of "the gateway of the nth interface"), and I don't know why /etc/resolv.conf was empty with the initial order I used.  I had actually reversed the interfaces initially due to another problem I was having with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often there is some misunderstanding in what the 'default gateway' means. Usually there may be only *one* default gateway (there are exceptions, but not in your case). There is no need to have a gateway in network `192.168.57.0`, as it is directly attached.

Defining two gateways (one for each interface) seems to end up only one, depending on the sequence of the definitions. The same holds true for the DNS servers - they are not bound to a specific interface, so maybe depending on the sequence of defining/starting the interfaces the last definition wil be used.

You may change the sequence of the interface definitions (eth1, then eth0), if needed, but define `gateway 10.0.5.1` and `dns-...` with eth0 (or, if in doubt, the same with both interfaces).